# Failure in installation of mesa from source - undefined reference to llvm after running make command

Tags: drivers, make

I am trying to install the mesa package from the repository: [git://anongit.freedesktop.org/mesa/mesa](http://git://anongit.freedesktop.org/mesa/mesa). I have successfully run the following command from within the mesa folder:

```
$ ./autogen.sh                            \
      --prefix=$NVD                       \
      --enable-texture-float              \
      --enable-gles1                      \
      --enable-gles2                      \
      --enable-glx                        \
      --enable-egl                        \
      --enable-gallium-egl                \
      --enable-gallium-llvm               \
      --enable-shared-glapi               \
      --enable-gbm                        \
      --enable-glx-tls                    \
      --enable-dri                        \
      --enable-osmesa                     \
      --with-egl-platforms=x11,drm        \
      --with-gallium-drivers=nouveau      \
      --with-dri-drivers=nouveau          \
      --enable-vdpau

$./configure
```

However, when I run the make command with superuser permissions, I get the following error:

```
../../../../src/gallium/auxiliary/.libs/libgallium.a(lp_bld_misc.o): In function `llvm::RTDyldMemoryManager::getSymbolAddress(std::string const&)':
/usr/lib/llvm-3.8/include/llvm/ExecutionEngine/RTDyldMemoryManager.h:77: undefined reference to `llvm::RTDyldMemoryManager::getSymbolAddressInProcess(std::string const&)'
/usr/lib/llvm-3.8/include/llvm/ExecutionEngine/RTDyldMemoryManager.h:77: undefined reference to `llvm::RTDyldMemoryManager::getSymbolAddressInProcess(std::string const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:991: recipe for target 'gallium_dri.la' failed
make[4]: *** [gallium_dri.la] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/nouveau/mesa/src/gallium/targets/dri'
Makefile:620: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/nouveau/mesa/src/gallium'
Makefile:869: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/nouveau/mesa/src'
Makefile:660: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/nouveau/mesa/src'
Makefile:677: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? What version of `llvm-3.8-dev`?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, it is unnessecary to build `mesa` from source in Ubuntu. It will already be installed as part of Xorg. The three packages installed are `libglu1-mesa`, `libgl1-mesa-glx` and `libgl1-mesa-dri`.

If you really need to build `mesa`, then your problem is with the new(ish) c++11 ABI. As the links in [this bug report from Red Hat shows](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1193198), the problem is that your llvm has not been compiled with c++11. You may like to update your `llvm-3.8` installation with `sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade llvm-3.8`. Otherwise, you may like to install a newer version of `llvm` - `llvm-3.9`, `llvm-4.0` or `llvm-5.0` (recommended).